# Fundamental circuits - diodes

Tags: transistors, integrated-circuit, power-electronics

[image]

I'd have a question about fundamental circuits. What role does Q2 play in this circuit? It's inital bound like a diode. Thank you so much!

Comment: A small circuit like this and on it's own with zero provenance gives no clue. It isn't obvious so, explain where the circuit came from and who drew it and what should be attached to the input and what RL represents. Also why is it shown with a constant current source attached to Q1's emitter?

Comment: Why is this tagged op-amp? I don't see one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very clear to me what this circuit is doing without part values, but Q2 might be used as a temperature offset compensation for Q1 if they are the same device.

The other effect is that it also acts as a low leakage diode.

Comment: That's what crossed my mind, as well, before your answer showed up.

Comment: That's what I thought but I just wasn't sure. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think if it were used as diode (for ESD or such) you wouldn't have R2 there. Temperature-compensation for the bias network seems more likely to me.

Comment: The thing is R2 could be a 1ohm resistor and could be to avoid having negative voltage on the base of Q1.